# Eclipse does not recognize a child maven project as such

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a parent maven project in eclipse that I have called "pomproject".
I also have a child project that I have called pomprojectchild.
I think there is something in the configuration that is not correct.

Why when right-clicking, the same options do not appear in the parent project and in the child project?
Attached screenshots.
[image: Right click on the parent project --> properties]
[image: Menu]

[image: Right click on the child project --> properties]
[image: Menu]

Why is the menu of the parent project different from the menu of the child?
Is there something misconfigured?
Thanks in advance
All the best

pom.xml(parent)

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pomproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>pomproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>pomproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
  <modules>
    <module>pomprojectchild</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

pom.xml(child)

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.pomproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>pomproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.pomproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>pomprojectchild</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>pomprojectchild</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
</project>
```

I import the parent project with the child inside from eclipse.
[image: I import the project]

Comment: Please show the pom files of those two projects... and describe how you import that project into Eclipse?

Comment: The pomprojectchild properties now appear correctly when importing the project into eclipse again.
I don't know what error I was making, but importing it again as I show in the screenshot (the last one) resolved the problem.
Thank you so much!

Comment: The child projects seems to be already imported before (in the last screenshot for _Import as_ for both _Eclipse project_ is shown). Does the following help: delete the child projects without their content, then in the child projects delete the `.project` file and then right-click the project `pomproject` and choose _Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects..._

Comment: You should import a Maven project as a Maven project...and not via sources etc...